# IIS logging directories/files seperately

Tags: iis, web-server, logging

How can I log directories or files SEPERATELY? Different log files for each that I choose, not just for the "website" directly under "web sites". If IIS cannot natively do this, is there perhaps another way? I need the file accessed, referring URL, and if possible, IP address.

Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0 MicrosoftOfficeWebServer: 5.0_Pub
Windows Servers 2003 R2 Standard Edition Service Pack 2

Answer (score 1):

IIS logs are per site only.

Log Parser is a great tool for extracting a certain category of events from your logs, like every reuqest that took more than .5 seconds to process or every 404 returned.

WebTrends or AWStats sounds more like your tool, though. You point these tools at your logs, and they slice and dice your visits looking for trends to exploit or correct. They will help you pick out active or overlooked parts of your site and adjust accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I had a need to do something similar, but I ended up writing a script (perl in this case) that post-processed the log each day to create the per-directory logs I needed. It would have been nice to have a live way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

If the information you want is in the IIS log then you could use [LogParser](http://forums.iis.net/default.aspx?GroupID=51).
I haven't used it myself but you use SQL SELECT statements to extract date from the file.

Theres an example [here](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/tools/logparser/lpexamples.mspx) but you be better off with my first link.